# How to set focus on specific activity in flexganttfx

Tags: javafx, gantt-chart

I'm using Flexganttfx, and I'd like swipe to an specific activity in my gantt chart when I click in a term (this term is out gantt chart, but contains the reference for the activity object that I want to swipe to).

How to do this?

Comment: I don't know about Flexganttfx, but there is a method called `.requestFocus()` in JavaFX.
May be it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RanaDepto, but unfortunately the object Activity and their wrapper ActivityRef don't extends Node, that has the metod .requestFocus().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer into the flexganttfx's forum:

"there is no utility method for doing this, yet. You will need to call scrollTo() on the tree table view and then request a specific time on the timeline (Timeline.showTime())."

http://dlsc.com/forums/topic/setselectedactivity-scroll-to-row-and-activity/

In my case:

```
int rowIndex = gantt.getTreeTable().getRow(treeItem);
gantt.getTreeTable().scrollTo(rowIndex);
gantt.getTimeline().showTime(date);
```

This solves my problem, I hope to help someone :)